# Mock i18Next with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, i18next

I spent the entire day looking at this issue, trying different solutions, but nothing seems to work.

Here's a summary of my code:

```js
// lib/i18next.ts
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

... (i18next initialization boilerplate)

export default i18n;
export const t = (str, options?) => i18n.t(str, options);
```

Then in the file where the test is failing:

```js
import { t } from '../lib/i18next';

export function thingToTranslate() {
  t('key_1', { color: red }), // where key1 can be 'The house color is ' 
}
```

In the tests I have the following:

```js
// several imports

describe('my test', () => {
  it('does something', () ={
    expect(thingToTranslate()).toEqual('The house color is red');
  })
}
```

The above code fails with the test:

```js
Expected: "The house color is red"
Received: "key_1"
```

Things I tried so far:

- Mocking

```js
// several imports

jest.mock('i18next', () => ({
  use: () => this,
  init: () => { },
  t: k => k
}));

describe('my test', () => {
  it('does something', () ={
    expect(thingToTranslate()).toEqual('The house color is red');
  })
}
```

results in `TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined`. I tried several variations of the above. Either it returns the previous error (`Received: "key_1"`) or it returns the above.

- Config file

I also tried adding this file to my `__mocks__` directory (from the [react-i18next docs](https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing#example-configuration-for-testing)) and variations I found online

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',

    // have a common namespace used around the full app
    ns: ['translations'],
    defaultNS: 'translations',

    debug: true,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react!!
    },

    resources: { en: { translations: {} } },
  });

export default i18n;
```

but this yields

```
You are passing an undefined module! Please check the object you are passing to i18next.use()

      ## | };
      ## |
    > ## | i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
```

I am aware of similar posts that seem to work, but as I mentioned here, it's not working for me, but don't know what's wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mocking the entire lib, you can pass [`cimode`](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#changelanguage) as `lng` which will make the `t` function to return the key itself.

All you need to do is in your **tests** call the `changeLanguage`.

```js
i18next
  .changeLanguage('cimode')
```

Comment: Thank you. Changing the language indeed returns the key itself, but I'm back to the first error case where the key is not equal to the expected translation. Is there a way to return the actual translation? Do I need to initialize i18next in the tests?

Comment: The best practice for testing i18n is not relay on the real value since in some companies  content people write the values and may change them externaly, therefore, `cimode` was created to return the key, so it won't be change when external changes to the values are applied.